# Drupal 7: How to save form values with system_settings_form()?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to set up a simple settings form for a module I am building.

Currently I have just a fieldset and a single check box:

```
function my_module_settings() {
  $form = array();

  $config = my_module_default_settings();

  $form['my_module_settings'] = [
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Script options'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'script_config',
  ];

  $form['my_module_settings']['my_module_setting_scripts'] = array(
    'script_on' => array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => t('Enable Scripts'),
      '#default_value' => !empty($config['script_on']) ? $config['script_on'] : FALSE,
      '#group' => 'script_config',
    ),
  );

  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

This does render, but checking the checkbox and hitting save does not actually save anything in the form.

How can I make sure my form data saves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `system_settings_form()`, form data are saved in the `{variable}` database table, using form keys to name variables.

When the form is submitted, the `system_settings_form` submit handler won't use *'script_on'* but the form key.

> This function adds a submit handler and a submit button to a form
>   array. The submit function saves all the data in the form, using
>   variable_set(), to variables named the same as the keys in the form
>   array. Note that this means you should normally prefix your form array
>   keys with your module name, so that they are unique when passed into
>   variable_set().

This allows to use `variable_get('form_key')` to grab form data, meaning in your case you can directly map things like :

```
'#default_value' => variable_get('my_module_setting_scripts', !!$config['script_on']);
```

.. here with a ternary expression 'shortcut' (!!) for the fallback setting.